# How to show name starting only by A, or B

Tags: django-queryset

I've got a list of users that I would like to order in a list. The webpage is now showing all the users. I want to show only user starting by A or B for example, like this:

A________________________________
Albert

B________________________________
Bernard
Boris

C_________________________________
Charlie

I know how to show all the users:

```
`{% for user in user_list.objects.all %}
      {{ user.name }}
 {% endfor %}`
```

How can we filter user starting by A only?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really two parts:

1. How do I filter for users whose names start with *either* A or B?
2. How do I render my template with the filtered user queryset?

---

Django querysets can be filtered by multiple expresssions, however by default they are AND'ed together. The following would be nonsensical, since a string can't start with both 'a' AND 'b'

```py
User.objects.filter(name__istartswith='a').filter(name__istartswith='b')
```

To OR the expressions, you need to use `Q` objects.

```py
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(Q(name__istartswith='a') | Q(name__istartswith='b'))
```

---

You cannot trivially construct this filter inside of the template as the syntax is intentionally limited. This prevents templates from containing too much logic. Instead, you'll need to override the `user_list` inside of the view. If you're using the generic `ListView` class, you can accomplish this by overriding [`get_queryset`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_queryset).